# Visual studio Solution and TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I and a friend are working on a project and everything is going great.
We are using source control to keep track of our changes etc.

We are facing one problem though. We're migrating some projects from a 2013 server to a 2016 and have to migrate everything to a new solution. However, when I make 4 new projects I can see them in my solution and check them in ofc. They appear online in the source control and he can also do a "Get latest" which then downloads my new projects onto he's a computer. (So far so good)

What happens then is the projects that I have created don't appear to be inside his a solution but is available locally. In order for him to see the projects he has to add them manually (Add existing item). Is there another way that we haven't seen or used so he immediately gets the projects in the solution whenever he does a pull? because this migration can go up to 100 projects and we don't really want to add them 1 by 1.

Every help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're adding them to a solution, and the solution is under source control, the projects should show up _automagically_ (although Visual Studio will probably ask you if you want to reload the solution). If he has pending changes for the solution when he gets the latest version, his `.sln` might not be updated.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be an issue in migration , could you please confirm that new project and old projects are on same version